# How can i save and fetch MKPolyline by using core data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I am new for iOS, and working on google maps.

I would like to save my travelled route map (with polyline) into my Core Data based on Key Values.

Code using till for saving(from runkeeper app)

```
- (void)saveRun
{
Run *newRun = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Run"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

newRun.distance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.distance];
newRun.duration = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.seconds];
newRun.timestamp = [NSDate date];

NSMutableArray *locationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CLLocation *location in self.locations) {
    Location *locationObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    locationObject.timestamp = location.timestamp;
    locationObject.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
    locationObject.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
    [locationArray addObject:locationObject];
}

newRun.locations = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:locationArray];
self.run = newRun;

// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }
}
```

Then after i would like to Fetch that Polyline details based on Key Values and display on MapView.

For fetching

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)mapRegion
{
  MKCoordinateRegion region;
  Location *initialLoc = self.run.locations.firstObject;

float minLat = initialLoc.latitude.floatValue;
float minLng = initialLoc.longitude.floatValue;
float maxLat = initialLoc.latitude.floatValue;
float maxLng = initialLoc.longitude.floatValue;

for (Location *location in self.run.locations) {
    if (location.latitude.floatValue < minLat) {
        minLat = location.latitude.floatValue;
    }
    if (location.longitude.floatValue < minLng) {
        minLng = location.longitude.floatValue;
    }
    if (location.latitude.floatValue > maxLat) {
        maxLat = location.latitude.floatValue;
    }
    if (location.longitude.floatValue > maxLng) {
        maxLng = location.longitude.floatValue;
    }
}

region.center.latitude = (minLat + maxLat) / 2.0f;
region.center.longitude = (minLng + maxLng) / 2.0f;

region.span.latitudeDelta = (maxLat - minLat) * 1.1f; // 10% padding
region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLng - minLng) * 1.1f; // 10% padding

return region;
}

- (MKPolyline *)polyLine {

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[self.run.locations.count];

for (int i = 0; i < self.run.locations.count; i++) {
    Location *location = [self.run.locations objectAtIndex:i];
    coords[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude.doubleValue,location.longitude.doubleValue);
}

return [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:self.run.locations.count];
}
- (void)loadMap
{
if (self.run.locations.count > 0) {

    self.mapView.hidden = NO;

    // set the map bounds
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self mapRegion]];

    // make the line(s!) on the map
    NSArray *colorSegmentArray = [MathController colorSegmentsForLocations:self.run.locations.array];
   [self.mapView addOverlays:colorSegmentArray];
    //[self.mapView addOverlay:[self polyLine]];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[[BadgeController defaultController] annotationsForRun:self.run]];
} else {

    // no locations were found!
    self.mapView.hidden = YES;

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:@"Sorry, this run has no locations saved."
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Main thing is save the path using Key values and fetch with that key value only.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: You need to priced more information, specifically how you want to store the path, and how you want to be able to fetch it.  Fetch the entire path based on a name?  Search for any path that contains common points, or points within a certain distance?  Here is a core data tutorial that incorporates using some map info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73984/make-app-like-runkeeper-part-1

Comment: ya want to fetch entire path based on a name only ... i tried runkeeper, in that application path just moving to the other view controller, but i want save the path based on names and also fetch by using that names only .

Comment: Sorry, but your question still is not clear as to what you are trying to accomplish.  The statement "Main thing is save the path using Key values and fetch with that key value only" can mean almost anything.  Please be specific about what you want to do.

Comment: Am drawing lines on the map when i am moving, i want to save that lines by pressing the button, with particular key values and after i want fetch that any one line based on the key value for displaying on the mapview.